# Close alt not changed on close operation

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, tooltips

Before voting to close my own question, it shows

```
close(2)
and alt message as "2 more vote to close this question"
```

This doesn't change even after I voted to close my question. But it just change after I refreshed. So is this a bug?

**Edit:**
Alt message doesn't change even after I voted to close my question. But it just change after I refreshed. So is this a bug?

Comment: could also reproduce it... I'll take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed as soon as the next build rolls out (revision 2013.7.9.826)

Answer (score 2):

I think this happened with you:

When you open/load/reload the question page it had 2 close votes. But before you hover on the close link (i.e. `close(2)`) the question got another close vote (i.e. 3rd vote). So it show you *"2 more vote to close this question"* (Because you didn't load the tooltip before).

When you voted to close the question it doesn't load the question (after your close vote) so it still show you the same message in tooltip (i.e. *2 more vote...*). If you refresh the page (before it get closed) it will show you *"You voted to close as '(the close reason)'. 1 more vote from another user is needed to close this question."* (in this case).

You can test it on another question where there are maximum 3 close votes. But don't close the question just to test it.

Comment: But can I redo my close vote after test?

Comment: @vusan - No. You can't. That's why I told that don't close the question just to test it. But if you think the question should be closed then only test it.

Comment: Again it happen. Alt message do not changed but the message change from `close` to `close(1)`.

Comment: @vusan - Because the tooltip doesn't reload after our close vote. Just refresh the page and see the tooltip again.